# JSON, jQueryUI Autocomplete, AJAX - Cannot get data when array is not local

Tags: ajax, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have searched stackoverflow, as well as the web for some insight into how to get the jQueryUI Autocomplete plugin working with my JSON data, and I'm at a loss. I had it working like a charm with a local data array. I was able to pull values and build html.

I ran into a problem when I had to pull JSON form this source:

```
/Search/AjaxFindPeopleProperties2
```

?txtSearch=ca pulls up the test data that I am trying to loop through, when I type in 'ca' to populate the autocomplete list. One of the problems is that ?term=ca is appended to the url instead of ?txtSearch=ca and I'm not sure how to change it.

This is an example of the data:

```
{

"MatchedProperties": [
    {
        "Id": 201,
        "Name": "Carlyle Center",
        "Description": "Comfort, convenience and style are just a few of the features you'll ...",
        "ImageUrl": "/Photos/n/225/4989/PU__ThumbnailRS.jpg"
    }

 ]

}
```

...and here is the ajax call I'm trying to implement:

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    val = $("#txtSearch").val();

    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "/Search/AjaxFindPeopleProperties2",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

        success: function (data) {
            $('#txtSearch').autocomplete({
                minLength: 0,
                source: data.d, //not sure what this is or if it's correct
                focus: function (event, ui) {
                    $('#txtSearch').val(ui.item.MatchedProperties.Name);

                        $.widget("custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {

                            //customize menu item html here
                            _renderItem: function (ul, item) {
                                return $("<li class='suggested-search-item" + " " + currentCategory + "'></li>")
                            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                            .append($("<a><img src='" + item.MatchedProperties.ImageUrl + "' /><span class='name'>" + item.MatchedProperties.Name + "</span><span class='location'>" + "item.location" + "</span><span class='description'>" + item.MatchedProperties.Description + "</span></a>"))
                            .appendTo(ul);
                            },

                            _renderMenu: function (ul, items) {
                                var self = this,
                                currentCategory = "Properties Static Test Category";
                                $.each(items, function (index, item) {
                                    if (item.category != currentCategory) {
                                        ul.append("<li class='suggested-search-category ui-autocomplete-category'>" + currentCategory + "</li>");
                                        //currentCategory = item.category;
                                    }
                                    self._renderItem(ul, item);
                                });
                            }

                        }//END: widget
                    //return false;
                },
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    $('#txtSearch').val(ui.item.MatchedProperties.Name);
                    //$('#selectedValue').text("Selected value:" + ui.item.Abbreviation);
                    return false;
                }
            });
        },

        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus);
        }

    }); //END ajax





}); //END: doc ready
```

and I'm initializing here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //initialize autocomplete
$("#txtSearch").autocomplete({ //autocomplete with category support
        /*basic settings*/
        delay: 0,
        source: "/Search/AjaxFindPeopleProperties2",
        autoFocus: true,
        minLength: 2 //can adjust this to determine how many characters need to be entered before autocomplete will kick in
    });
//set auto fucus
    $("#txtSearch").autocomplete("option", "autoFocus", true);


</script>
```

any help would be great...

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to place your items in categories? (just wondering, I see a custom widget definition that puts items in categories in the dropdown menu)

Comment: Can you show more of the data returned by the service ? the `source` option expects an array (whether it's an array of strings, or an array of objects of type `{ label: '', value: ''}`. When the source is an url, you should return json but still representing an array. The piece of data you show does not look like an array (see [doc](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) / overview text)